# How to Add a Custom Contract to Trust Wallet

Tags: erc-20, usdt, trustwallet

If I deploy a contract on the Ethereum Mainnet or a testnet like Sepolia and store USDT in that contract, will Trust Wallet display my balance and the USDT stored in that custom contract?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add custom tokens to Trust Wallet by entering the contract address and network details. Trust Wallet might show your USDT balance in a custom contract if it's designed for token interaction.

Refer to these Trust Wallet's community resources:

1. https://community.trustwallet.com/t/how-to-add-a-custom-token/213
2. https://community.trustwallet.com/t/how-to-submit-a-token-logo